# Run executable on gulp-watch

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, gulp-watch

I want to run an executable or a "non-javascript script" on the event `add` using `gulp-watch`(so server/developer-side, not user-side). From searching around I'm guessing I need to use `ajax` as I want to avoid php, but this seems a bit roundabout. Is it possible to do this using `node.js` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that you use it with gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
var exec = require('gulp-exec');

function isAdded(file) {
  return file.event === 'add';
}

var filterAdded = filter(isAdded);

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('**/*.js')
    .pipe(watch('**/*.js'))
    .pipe(filterAdded)
    .pipe(exec('ls -la'))
    .pipe(filterAdded.restore());
});
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for